# contact form 7 checkbox styling

Tags: html, css, contact-form-7

first of all i apologise in advance for my ignorance, im very new to this kind of thing, but trying to learn..

So my problem is im trying to create 6 check boxes in contact form 7 displayed in a grid of 6, the check boxes i have created with help from this site.

```css
.select-size input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #FD484E;
  line-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 5px;
}

#windows:checked~label[for="windows"],
#doors:checked~label[for="doors"],
#roofline:checked~label[for="roofline"],
#conservatories:checked~label[for="conservatories"],
#extensions:checked~label[for="extensions"],
#repairs:checked~label[for="repairs"] {
  background: #FD484E;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="select-size">
  <input type="checkbox" name="s-size" id="windows" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="s-size" id="doors" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="s-size" id="roofline" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="s-size" id="conservatories" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="s-size" id="extensions" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="s-size" id="repairs" />

  <label for="windows">Windows</label>
  <label for="doors">Doors</label>
  <label for="roofline">Roofline</label>
  <label for="conservatories">Conservatories</label>
  <label for="extensions">Extensions</label>
  <label for="repairs">Repairs</label>
</div>
```

my contact form 7 code:

```html
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">

[text* your-name placeholder "Your Name"]

[email* your-email placeholder "Your Email"]

[tel* tel-395 placeholder "Your Telephone"]



</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">

[checkbox* checkbox-495 id:checkbox use_label_element "Windows" "Doors" "Conservatories" "Roofline" "Extensions" "Repairs"]

</div>
</div>

<div class="row vertical-center">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
<p>We will contact you within one business day.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 submit-button-align-right">
[submit "Send Message"]
</div>
</div>
```

now.... I get stuck on how i merge the two together? this is way over my head, i can generally get by on general bits but this really has me stumped.

if anyone can give me any help it will be very much appreciated

Thanks in Advance,

regards

Comment: actually what you want, do you want to diaplay the 2 checkboxes together and other in 2-2 pair

Comment: I’m trying to display two rows of 3

Answer (score 0):

The format used by Contact Form 7 is a little different from your HTML, but there are some targeting options that should be sufficient to grab any element you need.

When creating your form, you'll generate a checkbox shortcode that looks something like this

```
[checkbox my-checkbox id:my-checkboxes use_label_element "foo" "bar"]

This code will generate:
```

- A set of two checkboxes

  - Each of the two is wrapped in a  element (the text itself is
    in a )
  - A parent element with the id="my-checkboxes"`

    So the output markup will look something like this (along with some
    wpcf7 and Wordpress classes)

  foo
      
      
        bar

Since you have an ID on the parent element, you can target this specific part of the form and elements within it using selectors in CSS or JQuery.

For example #mycheckboxes > label > input and #mycheckboxes > label > input + span.

For better targeting options, you can also create one checkbox per shortcode and assign an ID to each  checkbox container.

```
[checkbox my-checkbox id:a-checkbox use_label_element "foo"]
[checkbox my-checkbox2 id:another-checkbox use_label_element "bar"]
```

hope this help thank u

Comment: Thank you for that, it did help, I’ve targeted the individual check boxes but now I have the original check box inside of the “new” defined box with the text but it’s displaying vertical in one column. I feel this might be too much for me, with the knowledge I have.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this for 3 box per row
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
      <label for="windows">Windows</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="s-size" id="windows" />
      <label for="doors">Doors</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="s-size" id="doors" />
      <label for="roofline">Roofline</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="s-size" id="roofline" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
      <label for="conservatories">Conservatories</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="s-size" id="conservatories" />
      <label for="extensions">Extensions</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="s-size" id="extensions" />
      <label for="repairs">Repairs</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="s-size" id="repairs" />
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

getting there, box doesn't highlight on selection, and can't hide the original checkbox.

anyone?

[contact snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgFyO.jpg)

```css
#checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #FD484E;
  line-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 2px;
}

#windows:checked~label[for="windows"],
#doors:checked~label[for="doors"],
#roofline:checked~label[for="roofline"],
#conservatories:checked~label[for="conservatories"],
#extensions:checked~label[for="extensions"],
#repairs:checked~label[for="repairs"] {
  background: #FD484E;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">

    [text* your-name placeholder "Your Name"] [email* your-email placeholder "Your Email"] [tel* tel-395 placeholder "Your Telephone"]



  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">

    [checkbox* checkbox-203 id:windows class:checkbox use_label_element "Windows"] [checkbox* checkbox-203 id:doors class:checkbox use_label_element "Doors"] [checkbox* checkbox-203 id:conservatories class:checkbox use_label_element "Conservatories"] [checkbox*
    checkbox-203 id:roofline class:checkbox use_label_element "Roofline"] [checkbox* checkbox-203 id:extensions class:checkbox use_label_element "Extensions"] [checkbox* checkbox-203 id:repairs class:checkbox use_label_element "Repairs"]

  </div>
</div>

<div class="row vertical-center">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
    <p>We will contact you within one business day.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 submit-button-align-right">
    [submit "Send Message"]
  </div>
</div>
```